# Easier fix for water leaking under frameless shower door?

Tags: bathroom, shower, tile, leak, grout

I have recently moved into a new place and one of the bathrooms has a frameless shower door with a sweep already installed under it. When the shower is used, water slowly seeps under I think via a grout line that sits just below the length of the sweep; I can see the water slowly pooling in the grout line (on both sides of the door) and eventually spilling over onto the bathroom floor when enough has collected. I have found similar posts and it seems like the issue may be that the tiles under the door should be (or should have been since they were placed at least) sloped inward more to prevent water from flowing outward, but is there anything else I can try besides having the tilework redone? Thanks!

[Large pic](https://imgur.com/kk8xRwG)

[Close up of groove under the sweep](https://imgur.com/0mlycfi)

Comment: To clarify—the water is leaking through the grout groove—or are there other leaks?  If that's the only one, seems to me the solution is to layer on *something*—maybe more grout, maybe some caulk or other sealant—to make the grout area flush with the tile.

Comment: The water is only coming through the grout groove as far as I can tell. I asked a contractor about layering grout or caulk on the groove to make it flush and he said it would be a temporary or incorrect solution (he mentioned grout stacking) but didn't really elaborate why that wouldn't be permanent. I have had the same thought but was dissuaded after speaking with the contractor, that seems like a simple enough fix though.

Comment: Should be a relatively simple effort to at least try it.